# Automatically add HStore extension Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm developing on a django app that has a directory like so:

App:

```
manage.py
  --App1:
    -models.py
    -etc.
  --App2:
    -models.py
    -etc.
  --App3:
    -models.py
    -etc.
```

Many of them use HStore field(s) in the model definition file and when I go to migrate them each time I have to do this sequence:

1. run `python manage.py makemigrations {app 1,2,3 and so on here}`
2. Add   HStoreExtension() to operations=[] in the first migration file like: 0001_initial.py

It becomes tedious to do that when there's a ton of migrations for one app. I realize there may be better ways to structure the application but that's how it was built.

Is there any way to avoid having to "makemigrations" then add the hstore extension to the operations each time? I don't want to create a lot of manual work for others to spin up the app.

I know there are similar questions where the solution is to run a query to the database to add the extension. In this multiple subdirectory apps situation would I just include that in the top level application **init** file?

Comment: Any reason to use `hstore` instead of the built-in `jsonb` which gives you the pretty much the same features (and even some more)

Comment: "*In this multiple subdirectory apps situation*" - the database doesn't care how many applications use it, or how many modules/subdirectories an application hast. You need to create the extension once for every database that is created using `CREATE DATABASE`. If you install the needed extension in the `template1` database, then all _future_ databases will automatically have that extension as well.

Comment: Im using Hstore because that is what the app is using. I have no say over whether it is used or not. I realize I can run a script on the database one time and be done, but Im limited to what I can do inside django itself.